# PowerShell - how to check "Not Contains" clause?

Tags: powershell, path

I want to check if PATH in windows server contains some string. If it doesn't I wish to add it to the **PATH**. I want to add this **"CommonLib**" folder.
I try to do it immediately in IF clause:

```
  > $CommonLib="C:\Program Files\Front\CommonLib"
  > if (($env:Path -split ";").NotContains($CommonLib)) {Write-Host "executing the code"}
    InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'NotContains'.
```

**Contains** is recognized (I can do it probably by executing the code in ELSE clause) but **NotContains** isn't.
How can I resolve this?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` branch is a solid option. It's simple to write and understand. Like so,

```
if (($env:Path -split ";").Contains($CommonLib)) {
  Write-Host "$CommonLib is in path"
} else {
  Write-Host "$CommonLib is NOT in path"
}
```

It's also possible to do the test and store the result in a variable. Logic operators like `-not` can be used to invert its value. It's usually much more clear to test if `something is something` than `someting is not someting`. Like so,

```
$CLInPath = ($env:Path -split ";").Contains($CommonLib)
if(-not $CLInPath) {
  Write-Host "$CommonLib is NOT in path"    
}
```

This avoids `if..else` branching, which is desired if the other branch doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `not` operator with the `Contains` function.

```
if (!($env:Path -split ";").Contains($CommonLib)) {Write-Host "executing the code"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here provide viable alternatives to your issue and arguably better approaches, but to answer your *specific* question, you need to use the `-NotContains` operator as so:

```
if (($env:Path -split ";") -NotContains $CommonLib) {
    Write-Host "executing the code"
}
```